# how to integrate zksforce with native ios and create custom login to get fields of sales force user

Tags: ios, xcode, salesforce

i try this to custom login with user name and password + security token. but it return error or exception like

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'INVALID_LOGIN', reason: 'INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x018fb5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0167e8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   lead miner sales force              0x0001932a -[ZKBaseClient sendRequest:name:returnRoot:] + 2266
    3   lead miner sales force              0x0001882a -[ZKBaseClient sendRequest:name:] + 90
    4   lead miner sales force              0x00004516 -[ZKSoapLogin login] + 358
    5   lead miner sales force              0x000107c1 -[ZKSforceClient soapLogin:] + 65
    6   lead miner sales force              0x00010965 -[ZKSforceClient login:password:] + 277
    7   lead miner sales force              0x0000b0fb -[loginViewController loginbutton:] + 315
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01690874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    9   UIKit                               0x003ee0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    10  UIKit                               0x003ee04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    11  UIKit                               0x004e60c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    12  UIKit                               0x004e6484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    13  UIKit                               0x004e5733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    14  UIKit                               0x0042b51d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    15  UIKit                               0x0042c184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    16  UIKit                               0x003ffe86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    17  UIKit                               0x003ea18f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0188483f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x018841cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x018a129e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x018a0ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x018a08db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x038a09e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x038a0809 GSEventRun + 104
    25  UIKit                               0x003ecd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    26  lead miner sales force              0x0001bd42 main + 130
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x020a370d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type ZKSoapException
```

Thank you for kind replay....

```
-(IBAction)loginbutton:(id)sender
{

NSString *username=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",usernamefield.text];
NSString *password=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",passwordfield.text];

ZKSforceClient *sforce = [[ZKSforceClient alloc] init];
[sforce login:username password:password];

ZKDescribeSObject *taskDescribe = [sforce describeSObject:@"Task"];
NSLog(@"url for the new Task page is %@", [taskDescribe urlNew]);
[sforce release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in ZKSforce, the `login:` call (and all other calls that goto the server) will throw a [ZKSoapException](https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce/blob/master/zkSforce/zkSoapException.h) if the server returns a soap fault, which it'll do if your credentials are invalid (which is what is reported in the stack trace you've shown). You need to use Objective-C's exception handling to catch this exception and process it, e.g.

```
@try {
    [sforce login:username password:password];
    ZKDescribeSObject *task = [sforce describeSObject:@"Task"];

} @catch (ZKSoapException *ex) {
   NSLog(@"login failed %@", [ex reason]);
   // show to user etc, whatever you want to do when login fails.
}
```

You need to compile with objective-c exceptions enabled for your project, which i believe has been the default for a while now.

Comment: Thanks for your kind replay but i also try your answer but it also show me the INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out. but i give the correct sandbox test domain for login but i cannot able to login. thanks advance..

Comment: If you want to login to sandbox, you need to call the setLoginHostAndProtocol: method passing https://test.salesforce.com before calling login

Answer (score 1):

In swift you can use this.

```
let username = "abc@gmail.com"
let password = "1234" + "yourtoken"
let client = ZKSforceClient()
client.performLogin(username, password: password, fail:{ (fail) in
            print(fail)

        }) { (success) in
            print(success)

        }
```

It will give you proper exception handling with fail and success.Hope it will work!!

Comment: Hey @vikram I am using same code u have provided, but I got this error - : Use of unresolved identifier 'zksforceCLient'. in swift

Comment: Can you please provide the console log, and please verify the ZKSforceClient sdk.

Comment: You need to import ZKSforce. Where ever you are using above code.